# Update to Mailer.cs not changing based on email

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, email

I had to change the email addresses that are involved in an app to a different set. The app just sends notifications when a form is submitted to the user and the admin for a confirmation. I went into the app files and did nothing but switch out the email address in the mailer.cs file. It doesn't seem to be effecting anything and it's still going to the old email and using the old email when sent to the user. Do I need to do more than that? This is an old app and I'm actually in the process of creating an updated replacement in a back-burning project, I'm not quite familiar with the detailed workings of it. I am manually editing these files and not using the UI if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a web application project? If so you need to build it through visual studio.
If it was created as a website project then try touching the web.config (like putting in a space or a line break anywhere and hit save) so it may try to re-compile.

Comment: Yes its a web app. I'll go into visual studio for the update. I have to switch OS everytime I work on a visual studio project so I thought a manual change would work so I could avoid doing that.

Comment: Rebuild it and then program it to read the email address from a node in the `<appSettings>` block of web.config. This will save future headaches, as you wont have to mess with the code to change it again.